# Macro to run different macros by criteria - depending on if specific cells are empty/not

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with defined macros that are opening specific PPT files.
I'm looking for a VBA code that will run a specific macro based on if certain cells are empty and other are not.

For example:
If cells B1 and B2 are empty but cell B3 isn't --> then run Macro1
If cells B1, B2 & B3 are empty but cell B4 isn't --> then run Macro2

Is it possible?
Many thanks!

Comment: Make a Truth Diagram (http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/gatesfunc/TruthMain.htm)

It will help you see the different cases.

Comment: Based on the diagram, do a Select Case

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the quick answer! most chances I missed something there... Report 3 should be activated when d8 & d9 ARE NOT EMPTY and d10 is empty (sorry it was the other way)

```
    Sub Choose_Macro()

Dim v As Variant

With Worksheets("Reports")
    v = Application.Match(Chr(42), .Range("d8:d11"), 0)
    If Not IsError(v) Then
        Select Case CLng(v)
            Case 3
                Report_3
            Case 4
                Report_4
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    End If
End With
End Sub
```